# HTML div tag left, right margin properties work differently for different browsers

Tags: html

I have div tag as first element in html page. I want this element to be centered on a page. Hence, I set left and right margin properties of this div tag. e.g. margin-left:20%

However, margins take effect differently in different browsers and UI alignment differs browser to browser

How can I resolve this?

How to set margins so that they work same in all browsers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: if you just want to center it then do margin: 0 auto; provided you have a width set on the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DIV CENTERING**

Centering relative positioned div

```
#div {
  position: relative;  /* Or without position property | default is static */
  width: 960px;        /* Change to your needs */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can also use e.g. `margin: 0 auto 20px;` where `0` is top, `auto` is left/right and `20px` is bottom.

---

Centering absolute positioned div

```
#div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 960px;        /* Change to your needs */
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -480px; /* Margin left is - width / 2 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following css property to your css class:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

Comment: My code is very simple as follows: <div style="margin-left:28%"> <table border="1"> <tr> <td>This is column one</td> <td>This is column two</td> </tr> </table> </div>

Comment: Also I am not using css currently. I have no problem using css though. I am trying to wrap my html table in div tag and then align div tag by setting its left and right margins to properly position it on page.

Comment: Replace style="margin-left:28%" with style="margin:0 auto;"

Comment: @user2494444 Avoid using inline styling if you're using HTML5, it's not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this will work better, provided you have a width set on the div

```
yourDiv {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Without knowing further info about your div, this is your best bet.
The first 0 is setting margin top and bottom to 0 and the auto is for margin left and right.

Comment: My code is very simple as follows: 
<div style="margin-left:28%">
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>This is column one</td>
    <td>This is column two</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

Comment: Also I am not using css currently. I have no problem using css though.  I am trying to wrap my html table in div tag and then align div tag by setting its left and right margins to properly position it on page

Comment: @user2494444 I am going to assume you want the div to be 44% in width since you have margin left 28% (assuming right 28% as well to be centered). Put a width on your div of 44%, and use the margin: 0 auto; note: even if you don't change your margin putting the width of 44% should still center your div in this scenario